# how to optimize search of MAC

Tags: c, arrays, search

I have to speed up searching of a MAC address in an array (size: 32k). I would like to get better performance out of it, I wrote a little example code to show the problem (mind that the MACs in the array are going to be random numbers (random ports, random vlans) and not nicely ordered (as displayed in the example code).
Now I'm looking for suggestions how I can improve that i.e. speed it up:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_MAC 32768
typedef unsigned char l2_mac_t[6];
typedef struct l2_s {
    int prt;
    int vln;
    l2_mac_t mac;
}l2_t;
int find_mac(int port, int vlan, l2_mac_t mac);
void fill_mac(void);

static l2_t arr[MAX_MAC] = {0};

int main (void) {
    int i = 0;
    int res = 0;
    fill_mac();
    for (i=0;i<MAX_MAC;i++) {
        res = find_mac(arr[i].prt,arr[i].vln,arr[i].mac);
        if (res%1000 == 0 )
            printf("Got MAC %d\n",res);
    }

}
int find_mac(int port, int vlan, l2_mac_t mac) {
    int i = 0;

    for (int i = 0;i< MAX_MAC; i++) {
        if (arr[i].prt == port) {
            if (arr[i].vln == vlan) {
                if (memcmp(arr[i].mac,mac,sizeof(l2_mac_t)) == 0 ) {
                //found
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void fill_mac(void) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i=0;i<MAX_MAC; i++) {
        arr[i].prt = 4;
        arr[i].vln = 10;
        arr[i].mac[5] = i%255;
        arr[i].mac[4] = i%65025;

    }
}
```

**Below is some edited code after getting some comments:**

Okay,

I was going to use a hash and came up with the below (which gives me a segfault as it doesn't want to allocate this much memory in `init()`). Plus, this feels kind of like using a sledge hammer at it, there must be a better way to hash this than than the below `MacSum()`, any suggestions are welcome!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_MAC 32768

#define MacSum(x)   (x)[0]*(2^24) \
                   +(x)[1]*(2^20) \
                   +(x)[2]*(2^16) \
                   +(x)[3]*(2^12)\
                   +(x)[4]*(2^8)\
                   +(x)[5]


typedef unsigned char l2_mac_t[6];
typedef struct l2_s {
    int prt;
    int vln;
    l2_mac_t mac;
}l2_t;

static unsigned short *L2Hash=0;

int find_mac(int port, int vlan, l2_mac_t mac);
void fill_mac(void);
void init(void);

static l2_t arr[MAX_MAC] = {0};

int main (void) {
    int i = 0;
    int res = 0;
    init();
    fill_mac();
    for (i=0;i<MAX_MAC;i++) {
        res = find_mac(arr[i].prt,arr[i].vln,arr[i].mac);
        /*if (res%1000 == 0 )
            printf("Got MAC %d\n",res);*/
    }

}
int find_mac(int port, int vlan, l2_mac_t mac) {
    int i = 0;
    int key = 0;

    key = MacSum(mac);
    if (memcmp(arr[key].mac,mac,sizeof(l2_mac_t)) == 0 ) {
        return key;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0;i< MAX_MAC; i++) {
            if (arr[i].prt == port) {
                if (arr[i].vln == vlan) {
                    if (memcmp(arr[i].mac,mac,sizeof(l2_mac_t)) == 0 ) {
                        return i;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void fill_mac(void) {
    int i = 0;
    int key = 0;
    for (i=0;i<MAX_MAC; i++) {
        arr[i].prt = 4;
        arr[i].vln = 10;
        arr[i].mac[5] = i%255;
        arr[i].mac[4] = i%65025;
        key = MacSum(arr[i].mac);
        L2Hash[key] = i;
    }
}

void init(void) {
    static int init = 0;
    if (init)
        return;
    L2Hash = (unsigned short*) malloc(0xffffffffffff*sizeof(unsigned short));
}
```

**For a further update to the question, scroll down to the second answer**

Comment: keep your array sorted and use a binary search

Comment: As long as the data structure is an array in random order, you cannot do better than linear search until you find a match. If you can change the data structure to something else, then you can do better.

Comment: @bruceg how can I efficiently populate a sorted array ("random" macs appearing at "random" times)

Comment: @Arkku any suggestion in addition to bruceg's idea?

Comment: Hash map, skip list, binary search tree, sqlite database, … etc. The possibilities are endless, it depends on what you need and can use (e.g., are there constraints on memory, disk space, use of external libraries with certain licenses). But even just to keep the array sorted, consider how frequent insertions are compared to look-ups. For a single look-up you potentially have to iterate through the whole unsorted array (in fact you always have to do that if there's no match) whereas binary search only needs a few comparisons, and the insertion is binary search + bulk copy + possibly realloc.

Comment: bulk copy is the keyword, I'll have a pre allocated memory of `MAX_MAC` "slots" I need to work with no `realloc` possible. Plain system, no `sqlite` available

Comment: Well, benchmark a single `memmove` of half your maximum slots and see how many iterations through the array are needed to offset that cost, then consider the frequency of insertions (`memmove`) vs the frequency of look-ups and how common it is to have a look-up with no results (= worst case).

Comment: Also, are your queries random or do they have patterns either regarding previous queries (e.g., if the same entry is likely to be queried again, can you cache it or move it) or insertions (e.g., if newest/oldest entries are more likely to be queried, change the direction of your search accordingly). But also consider implementing a simple hash map.

Comment: @cerr you store the MAC addresses someplace. If you can keep that someplace sorted you're ok.  If you are getting fed the MACs in random order into your program, you can use a standard data structure like a binary tree or hash table depending on your requirement.  For example, if you only do a lookup, then maybe a hash table is your best bet.  You would want to choose a hash table implement that allows for efficient inserting.  Then you're lookup would be constant time.

Comment: If you want to store 32,768 MAC addresses and you want an average of one address per hash bucket, you only need 32,768 hash buckets. Why are you allocating so ridiculously many? [Linear hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_hashing) is always a good option, but don't reinvent the wheel -- find a hash map implementation you like.

Comment: I'd use a _sorted_ linear array and a binary search. But, since have a _fixed_ maximum number of MACs you store, your hash only needs to be a maximum of _that_ size. That is, `MAX_MAC` or 32768. Usually, the hash array size is much less (e.g. `#define MAX_HASH 256` and the index into the hash array is taken modulo that (e.g. `key = MACSUM(x); key %= MAX_HASH;`) The hash is actually: `l2_t *hash[MAX_HASH];` Then, each struct needs a `next` pointer (i.e. singly linked list) and we do `for (l2 = hash[key];  l2 != NULL;  l2 = l2->next) { if (match ...) break; }

Comment: `malloc(0xffffffffffff*sizeof(unsigned short))` sounds like a *lot* of memory. Is that an allocation of 524TB?

Comment: @Arkku in response to your question about the randomness of queries: They are entirely random, i can no control when an entry may needs to be found. It may be invoked by user action.

Comment: @tadman I calculate 256TB but anyways, it obviously is not doable to use the MAC as a straight index into a hash. Check my alternative option below (second answer)

Answer (score 1):

stylistic note: nested `if()`s are hard to read. Some people prefer:

---

```
int find_mac(int port, int vlan, l2_mac_t mac) {
    int i = 0;

    for (int i = 0;i< MAX_MAC; i++) {
        if (arr[i].prt != port) continue;
        if (arr[i].vln != vlan) continue;
        if (memcmp(arr[i].mac,mac,sizeof(l2_mac_t)) continue;
        //found
        return i;
    }
return WHAT; //!!11!!1
}
```

---

[this should be a comment, but I needed the formatting.]

Comment: Guard conditions like this really simplify your loops.

Answer (score 0):

I followd some of the above suggestions and came up with the below code. I've now reduced the number of MACs to `1000` but I already get some:`Could not find MAC` messages. 
Anybody able to assist me here?
Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_MAC     1000
#define SHORT_INIT  0xFFFF

#define MacSum(x)   (x)[0]*(2^24) \
                   +(x)[1]*(2^20) \
                   +(x)[2]*(2^16) \
                   +(x)[3]*(2^12)\
                   +(x)[4]*(2^8)\
                   +(x)[5]

typedef unsigned char l2_mac_t[6];
typedef struct l2_s {
    int prt;
    int vln;
    l2_mac_t mac;
}l2_t;

static unsigned short l2hash[MAX_MAC]={0};

int find_mac(int port, int vlan, l2_mac_t mac);
void fill_mac_tab(void);
void init(void);
void mac_hash_add (int idx, l2_mac_t mac);

static l2_t arr[MAX_MAC] = {0};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------

int main (void) {
    int i = 0;
    int res = 0;
    init();
    fill_mac_tab();
    for (i=0;i<MAX_MAC;i++) {
        res = find_mac(arr[i].prt,arr[i].vln,arr[i].mac);
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------

void init(void) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i=0;i<MAX_MAC;i++)
        l2hash[i] = SHORT_INIT;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------

int find_mac(int port, int vlan, l2_mac_t mac) {
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;

    k = (MacSum(mac))%MAX_MAC;
    if (memcmp(arr[k].mac,mac,sizeof(l2_mac_t)) == 0 ) {
        printf("Found MAC %02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X at key %d\n",mac[0],mac[1],mac[2],mac[3],mac[4],mac[5],k);
        return k;
    } else {
        for (int i = k;i< MAX_MAC; i++ ) {
            if (arr[i].prt != port ) continue;
            if (arr[i].vln != vlan ) continue;
            if (memcmp( arr[i].mac,mac,sizeof(l2_mac_t) )) continue;
            printf("Found MAC %02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X\n",mac[0],mac[1],mac[2],mac[3],mac[4],mac[5]);
            return i;
        }
    }
    printf("Could not find MAC %02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X\n",mac[0],mac[1],mac[2],mac[3],mac[4],mac[5]);
    return -1;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------

void fill_mac_tab(void) {
    int i = 0;
    int o = 0;
    int key = 0;    
    for (i=0;i<MAX_MAC; i++) {
        // fill table
        arr[i].prt = 4;
        arr[i].vln = 10;       
        arr[i].mac[5] = i%255;
        if (i>255)
            arr[i].mac[4] = i%65025;
        mac_hash_add(i,arr[i].mac);
    }
}

void mac_hash_add (int idx, l2_mac_t mac) {
    int i = 0;
    int o = 0;
    int k = 0;
    k = (MacSum(arr[idx].mac))%MAX_MAC;
    printf("k %d\n",k);
    if(l2hash[k] == SHORT_INIT ) {
        l2hash[k] = i;
    } else {
        printf("k %d already used, find next\n",k);
        // find next empty spot in hash 
        for (o=k; o<MAX_MAC; o++) {
            if (l2hash[o] != SHORT_INIT ) continue;
            printf("using %d\n",o);
            l2hash[o] = i;
            return;
        }
        printf("unable to find empty key within range \n");
    }
}
```

**a working solution of the above looks like:**
It still takes a significant amount of time but it's much better than linear searching through the complete array for every MAC every time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_MAC     32768
#define SHORT_INIT  0xFFFF
#define OK          0
#define ERROR       -1

#define MacSum(x)   (x)[0]*(2^24) \
                   +(x)[1]*(2^20) \
                   +(x)[2]*(2^16) \
                   +(x)[3]*(2^12)\
                   +(x)[4]*(2^8)\
                   +(x)[5]

typedef unsigned char l2_mac_t[6];
typedef struct l2_s {
    int prt;
    int vln;
    l2_mac_t mac;
}l2_t;

static unsigned short l2hash[MAX_MAC]={0};

int find_mac(int port, int vlan, l2_mac_t mac);
int fill_mac_tab(void);
void init(void);
int mac_hash_add (int idx, l2_mac_t mac);

static l2_t arr[MAX_MAC] = {0};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------

int main (void) {
    int i = 0;
    int rv = OK;
    init();
    printf("insert\n");
    rv = fill_mac_tab();
    if (rv) {
        printf("ERROR: fill_mac_tab() returned %d\n",rv);
        exit (rv);
    }
    printf("find\n");
    for (i=0;i<MAX_MAC;i++) {
        rv = find_mac(arr[i].prt,arr[i].vln,arr[i].mac);
        if (rv <0) {
            printf("ERROR: find_mac() returned %d\n",rv);
            exit(rv);
        }
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------

void init(void) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i=0;i<MAX_MAC;i++)
        l2hash[i] = SHORT_INIT;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------

int find_mac(int port, int vlan, l2_mac_t mac) {
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;

    k = (MacSum(mac))%MAX_MAC;
    if (memcmp(arr[k].mac,mac,sizeof(l2_mac_t)) == 0 ) {
        //printf("Found MAC %02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X at key %d\n",mac[0],mac[1],mac[2],mac[3],mac[4],mac[5],k);
        return k;
    } else {
        for (int i = k;i< MAX_MAC; i++ ) {
            if (arr[i].prt != port ) continue;
            if (arr[i].vln != vlan ) continue;
            if (memcmp( arr[i].mac,mac,sizeof(l2_mac_t) )) continue;
            //printf("Found MAC %02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X\n",mac[0],mac[1],mac[2],mac[3],mac[4],mac[5]);
            return i;
        }
        //printf("continue search from bottom\n");
        for (int i = 0;i< k; i++ ) {
            if (arr[i].prt != port ) continue;
            if (arr[i].vln != vlan ) continue;
            if (memcmp( arr[i].mac,mac,sizeof(l2_mac_t) )) continue;
            //printf("Found MAC %02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X\n",mac[0],mac[1],mac[2],mac[3],mac[4],mac[5]);
            return i;
        }
    }
    printf("Could not find MAC %02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X\n",mac[0],mac[1],mac[2],mac[3],mac[4],mac[5]);
    return ERROR;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------

int fill_mac_tab(void) {
    int i = 0;
    int o = 0;
    int key = 0;    
    int rv = OK;
    for (i=0;i<MAX_MAC; i++) {
        // fill table
        arr[i].prt = 4;
        arr[i].vln = 10;       
        arr[i].mac[5] = i%255;
        if (i>255)
            arr[i].mac[4] = i%65025;
        rv = mac_hash_add(i,arr[i].mac);
    }
    return rv;
}

int mac_hash_add (int idx, l2_mac_t mac) {
    int i = 0;
    int o = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int rv = OK;
    k = (MacSum(arr[idx].mac))%MAX_MAC;
    //printf("k %d\n",k);
    if(l2hash[k] == SHORT_INIT ) {
        l2hash[k] = i;
    } else {
        //printf("k %d already used, find next\n",k);
        // find next empty spot in hash 
        for (o=k; o<MAX_MAC; o++) {
            if (l2hash[o] != SHORT_INIT ) continue;
            //printf("using %d\n",o);
            l2hash[o] = i;
            return OK;
        }
        //printf("Continue search in bottom half\n");
        for (o=0; o<k; o++) {
            if (l2hash[o] != SHORT_INIT ) continue;
            //printf("using %d\n",o);
            l2hash[o] = i;
            return OK;
        }
        //printf("unable to find empty key within range \n");
        rv = ERROR;
    }
    return rv;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are using the hash to index ´arr´ without going through ´l2hash´.

Comment: @Arkku `arr` represents the area where the MACs are stored  and `l2hash` is the hash that should provide a quick lookup per MAC into `arr` to find the respective entry. I use`k`k in `find_mac()` to attempt a direct lookup (`memcmp() for verification`) if it's not right, I look at consecutive entries until the correct entry is found.  I have to implement searching from the bottom up once the top `MAX_MAC` is reached...

Comment: @Arkku yes, there is some benefit, it will first attempt to store the entry at `k` and if it does not suceed (because it's already occupied), it will increment and find the next entry - the likely-hood of the search being vastly faster than linearly searching through `MAX_MAC` every time, is quite significant!

Comment: But you are not using this benefit because your `find_mac` is broken, which is what my initial comment tried to say. =)

Comment: I think you're complicating what should be a simple solution to a ridiculous extreme here. All you need is a [**binary tree** structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) to store these in a way that's fast to insert and even faster to find. If you're doing a lot of insertion and removal you may want to use a self-balancing tree. This keeps your data sorted and fast no matter what happens.

Comment: @tadman but how can I quickly insert items into a binary tree? I'm a bit confused by that. I'm a "binary tree newbie"

Comment: There's a billion plus one examples of binary tree implementations in C, so you'll have to look around for one that you like and use that as a basis for your application. The Wikipedia page I linked to talks about the basics and has links to more exotic forms if you want to try those out. Most database indexes uses some form of binary tree to order data as they're simple, fast, and highly effective.